# Is there a way in Python to extract a single value from a pandas dataframe as a primative value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqldf

I have a data file with thousands of bills. When I try to extract a single cell value I notice the type is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Is there a way to extract an element as a primitive value like `float` or `int` directly from the dataframe or series?

```
    import pandasql as ps
    import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.read_csv(strFPath, sep='|', encoding='windows-1252')
    strQry = "SELECT SUM(BILLHOURS) AS 'BILLHOURS' FROM df"
    dfQry = ps.sqldf(strQry, globals())
    intHoursAll = float(dfQry.values[0].round(2))
```

Comment: It'd help to provide a [mre]. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you can use `iloc`

For example, to extract the value of the first column in the first row (0,0),

write this.

`value = df.iloc[0, 0]`

(value type depends on the data type of the cell. For example, numeric data can be int or float.)

Or

`value = df['your_column_name'].iloc[0]`

(df['your_column_name'] return pandas' series with all the values in that column)

Additionally, if you want to return the <class 'numpy.ndarray'> type,

write this.

`numpyArrayValues = df['column_name'].values`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.squeeze.html) to reduce a `Series` of one element to a scalar value:

```
>>> df
  OTHER  BILLHOURS
0     B          4
1     B          8
2     A          2
3     C          3
4     C          3
5     B          9
6     C          5
7     C          8
8     A          4
9     B          3

>>> ps.sqldf(strQry, globals()).squeeze()
49
```